# Ruamel.yaml: deserialize yaml into python class instaces without using tags

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes, ruamel.yaml

Imagine we have a folder of `.yaml` files containing kubernetes objects, let's say, deployments, configmaps and HPAs.

```
./file1.yaml # {'kind': 'Deployment', ... }, {'kind': 'ConfigMap', ...}
./file2.yaml # {'kind': 'ConfigMap', ... }, {'kind': 'HorizontalPodAutoscaler', ... }
```

I need to deserialize them into instances of a proper class, but unlike the regular deserialization method, I want to avoid relying on YAML tags and make a choice by YAML body instead (which is why i have doubts about `register_class()` approach). There is a key `'kind'` that should identify the proper class instance.

The end goal is to parse, modify and dump those objects back (**preserving comments and formatting**, so those classes would be a subclass of a CommentedMap or something similar).

Is there a way in ruamel.yaml how could I parse YAML into

```
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap

class KubeObjectBase(CommentedMap):

    def some_additional_func(self):
        pass

class Deployment(KubeObjectBase):

    def deployment_method(self):
        pass

class ConfigMap(KubeObjectBase):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what the YAML files actually look like. The part after `#` in your example
isn't correct YAML, so I made things up.

This doesn't affect processing to get what you want. As long as you have valid, loadable YAML,
just recursive over the data and replace entries.

You need to somehow map the value for `kind` to your actual classes. If there are not
that many classes just make a string to class dictionary, if you have many, you should
scan your Python files and create that map automatically (either from the class name
or from some class attribute):

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
FA = ruamel.yaml.comments.Format.attrib
from pathlib import Path

file1 = Path('file1.yaml')
file1.write_text("""\
- {'kind': 'Deployment', a: 1}
- kind: ConfigMap
  b:
    kind: Deployment
    c: 3
    x: 42
""")
file2 = Path('file2.yaml')
file2.write_text("""\
[
{'kind': 'ConfigMap', d: 4}, 
{'kind': 'HorizontalPodAutoscaler', e: 5},
]
""")

    
kob_map = {}
class KubeObjectBase(ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap):
    def some_additional_func(self):
        pass

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({', '.join([f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in self.items()])})"

class Deployment(KubeObjectBase):
    def deployment_method(self):
        pass
kob_map['Deployment'] = Deployment


class ConfigMap(KubeObjectBase):
    pass
kob_map['ConfigMap'] = ConfigMap


class HorizontalPodAutoscaler(KubeObjectBase):
    pass
kob_map['HorizontalPodAutoscaler'] = HorizontalPodAutoscaler

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
for v in kob_map.values():
    yaml.Representer.add_representer(v, yaml.Representer.represent_dict)


def un_kind(d, map):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            un_kind(v, map)
            try:
                if 'kind' in v:
                    # typ = map[v.pop('kind')]
                    typ = nv = map[v['kind']]
                    d[k] = typ(v)
                    setattr(nv, FA, v.fa)
                    setattr(nv, '_comment_attrib', v.ca)
            except TypeError:
                pass
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for idx, elem in enumerate(d):
            un_kind(elem, map)
            try:
                if 'kind' in elem:
                    # typ = map[elem.pop('kind')]
                    typ = map[elem['kind']]
                    d[idx] = nv = typ(elem)
                    setattr(nv, FA, elem.fa)
                    setattr(nv, '_comment_attrib', elem.ca)
            except TypeError:
                pass


for fn in Path('.').glob('*.yaml'):
    data = yaml.load(fn)
    print(f'{fn}:')
    un_kind(data, kob_map)
    print(list(data))
    yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
file1.yaml:
[Deployment(kind: Deployment, a: 1), ConfigMap(kind: ConfigMap, b: Deployment(kind: Deployment, c: 3, x: 42))]
- {kind: Deployment, a: 1}
- kind: ConfigMap
  b:
    kind: Deployment
    c: 3
    x: 42
file2.yaml:
[ConfigMap(kind: ConfigMap, d: 4), HorizontalPodAutoscaler(kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler, e: 5)]
[{kind: ConfigMap, d: 4}, {kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler, e: 5}]
```

Comment: Kubernetes objects I was talking about have a strict format: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/kubernetes-objects/. 'Kind' is always a top-level key. Anyway, I think I got your point. So, to get what I want, I need to 1) just parse yaml into geniune CommentedMap 2) apply recursion like [munchify](https://github.com/Infinidat/munch/blob/develop/munch/__init__.py#L420) to convert nested objects into my class. So, there is no built-in magic like defining a class, registering it with register_class() or a decorator and then just obtaining proper instances

Comment: No there is no built in method where you can register a key and if a mapping has a key, get a class associated with the mapping. `register_class` is for handling tags in YAML documents. My `un_kind` handles both nested collections (mapping, sequence) that can occur in YAML, munchify only seems to be more restrictive. Of course you can create the classes on the fly by adapting the constructor for mappings in `ruamel.yaml`, but that makes what happens far more magical/intransparent then walking the data structure afterwards.

Comment: In editing your question I realised you wanted to be able to dump things back. I updated the answer to make that possible. For one thing, you don't want to pop the 'kind' key in that case, and you want to copy the original formatting information, to get the same dump as what you loaded. If the originals have comments those should be preserved as well.